# General Linear Group over F

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I understand that for the real numbers $GL_{n}(R)$ is the set of $n$ by $n$ matrices with real entries and nonzero determinant. If we consider a general linear group over an arbitrary field $F$ I know that the entries are from the field $F$, but does this also mean that the determinant is not equal to $0$ the real number or the determinant is not equal to the additive identity $0_{F}$?

Comment: determinant is a function from the set $GL_n(F)$ to its scalar field $F$. So, the $0$ is ofcourse the addtive identity of $F$.

Comment: Another way to think of the general linear group is as the group of invertible linear transformations.  And a linear transformation is invertible iff its determinant is nonzero.  All of this can be said regardless of what field you use.